# How to Add a Border to Dynamically Populated Content, Except for the external borders in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I am trying to create a grid system where content will be populated dynamically, so I will not know the exact amount of elements when created. What I have so far is each element is added to a flexbox container that holds 3 elements in each row. If there are more than 3 elements then the next element would go to the next row and so on. With that said what I am trying to do is add borders around each element minus the outside ones. So it would look something like this.

```
__|__|__
__|__|__
  |  |
```

The issue I have been having is I have been adding a bottom border and a right border to every element and then would add a border of 0 to every 3rd child using nth-child(3n). But that doesn't fix the issue with the bottom border on the bottom row and it comes out looking like this for me:

```
__|__|__
__|__|__
__|__|__
```

I am not sure the best way to target that bottom border and remove it because since the content is being populated dynamically I won't know the exact amount of elements that will be on that bottom row because it could be 1, 2, or 3 elements. So what would be the best way to get the results I am looking for? Is it possible to do this with CSS alone or will I need javascript to do this? Here is the code I am currently using:

```
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexElement {
        width: 33.33%;
        border-right: solid 2px #e1e1e1;
        border-bottom: solid 2px #e1e1e1;

        &:nth-child(3n), &:last-child {
         border-right: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding the border to the top and excluding the first three elements.

**Solution**

```
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexElement {
  width: 33.33%;
  border-right: solid 2px #e1e1e1;

  // Styles start on the 4th child
  &:nth-child(n+4) {
    border-top: solid 2px #e1e1e1;
  }

  &:nth-child(3n), &:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qhwf376a/4/)